# Solve it through LCM and HCF

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

**Please help me regarding this math question.
The problem whould be solved through HCF and LCM.**

> Four friends go for an evening walk together. Their paces measure $75$ cm, $80$ cm and $90$ cm respectively. Find the minimum distance each should cover to walk the same distance in complete (whole) paces.

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: You gave us 4 friends but only 3 paces?

Comment: Like *The Three Musketeers* ;o)

Comment: The distance $D$  will be such that $D=75 P_1=80 P_2=90 P_3$ where $P_1,P_2, P_3$ are positive integers. So $D$ is divisible by $75,80,$ and $90$. So $D$ is a common multiple of $75,80,$ and $90.$  Let $E$ be the  $least$ common multiple of $75, 80,$ and $90$ Then $D\geq E.$  But we $can$ let $D=E,$  and  $P_1=E/75, P_2=E/80,$ and $P_3=E/90$,

Comment: I like to look at prime factors.  $75 = 3\cdot 5^2, 80 = 2^4\cdot5, 90 = 2\cdot3^2\cdot 5.$   The LCM will have prime factors $2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2.$  That is, it must meet the greatest power of each prime factor.

Comment: i was eager to know solution